# How to solve undefined reference to dynloadflag?

Tags: ats

My exact error link-time error is:

```
print.o: In function `_057_home_057_brandon_057_workspace_057_fsh_057_print_056_dats__dynload':
/home/brandon/workspace/fsh/print_dats.c:315: undefined reference to `_057_home_057_brandon_057_workspace_057_fsh_057_print_056_dats__dynloadflag'
```

The contents of `print.dats` is simply:

```
typedef FormatStruct = $extype"Format"

vtypedef Format(ll: addr) = (FormatStruct @ ll | ptr ll)

extern fun fmtputc{ll: addr}(fmt: Format(ll), cc: int): void = "mac#"
```

I have another dats file (main.dats) that doesn't seem to cause this issue. Is there some ATS library that needs to be added to LDFLAGS?

Comment: This error doesn't call for you to link in an ATS library. Most likely, you're either using the wrong commands to compile your code or you're not setting ATS_DYNLOADFLAG to 0 where you should. I can produce very similar errors to yours (f.e. `patscc print.dats` fails, obviously, with preceding complaints about a missing `main` function.), but I can't answer your question since you don't show how to replicate the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every DATS file in ATS is considered a module of some sort, which needs to be
initialized. If no initialization is needed, then you need to add the following
line in this DATS file

#define ATS_DYNLOADFLAG 0

Otherwise, you need to have a line like the following one

#dynload "/path/to/foo.dats"

in the main file where this module is used.